# What is the proper way to declare methods to be implemented by child classes?

Tags: c#, inheritance, implementation, icommand

I've created a parent class that has common methods, but there are methods that I want to be implemented by child classes. i.e. Click Execution methods.

What is the proper way to implement this?

```
public Parent {
    CancelCommand = new RelayCommand(CancelClicked, CancelCanExecute);
    private void CancelClick(object param) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}

public Child : Parent {
    private bool CancelCanExecute(object param) {
        // Do stuff
        return true;
    }
}
```

Where CancelClick is hosted by the parent class, and CancelCanExecute is handled by the child class.

Would I use an extern? Or should I use interfaces? If I use override in the child class, it doesn't force me to have to implement the method. I'm not sure I should change the parent class to an abstract because it has non-abstract methods and such.

Comment: You may have the base method as `abstract`, however you won't *force* the child class to implement it. For this purpose, you should write an `interface`.

Comment: @AndreCalil Only if that child class is `abstract` itself, but it can't be instantiated in that case.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Indeed. I don't usually write abstract classes/methods, and I've just verified that, in C#, you cannot have an abstract method in a non-abstract class. And that if you inherit from an abstract class, you *must* implement all the abstract methods. That's a little awkward, I'd say

Comment: @AndreCalil I find it to be quite logical, actually. Note that you *must* only if you aren't abstract as well. It all makes perfect sense.

Comment: @AndreCalil What other behavior would you want/expect? Instantiating a class with `abstract` methods is a bad idea IMO, so forbidding it is reasonable.

Comment: @AndreCalil Would there be anything preventing me from making my parent class an abstract class? I'm using it to group common functionality, and not going to make an instance of it. Trying to follow coding etiquette instead of just making a mash of code.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Right now I think that it makes sense. It would be awkward to have abstract methods on non-abstract classes, indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, here are your options:

**1.** Declare your **base class** as `abstract` and some methods as well

This approach has two good points: you will be free to implement common methods at the base class (that is, not all of them need to be `abstract`) while any abstract method will **must be** overridden at derived classes. There is one counter point (that you may be aware of): you can't instantiate it. That is, you can't do something like:

```
Base obj = new Base();
```

However, you stil will be able to do this:

```
Base obj = new Child();
```

**2.** Use **interfaces**

You may declare some interfaces to force your classes to implement some methods. However, the semantics between inheritance and interface is quite different. You must decide which is best for your.

IMHO, you would be fine with the first option.

Comment: The problem is that you can't decide in the base class you want to implement the interface, but leave the implementation to the child class. So by itself it doesn't work here.

Comment: @CodesInChaos note that `CancelCanExecute` is not declared at the base class. I believe that interfaces are one option, but an abstract base class is most suitable.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: you are wrong. Proof: `public abstract DisposableBase:IDisposable { public abstract void Dispose(); }`

Comment: @quetzalcoatl In that case the base class implements the full interface, and the child classes implement the abstract methods of the base class, which is subtly different from the derived class implementing the interface. Also you don't use interfaces as alternative to an abstract base class in that case, you use them in addition the the abstract base class. So you can't just partially implement interfaces on the base class as an alternative to using an abstract base class.

Comment: What good is creating base class that does not implement the interface X and that would force the derived ones to implement interface X? This is nonsense. Either the whole subtree is forced to implement it, or it is not. And of course I can partially implemnent the interface in the base class and leave rest to children: just implement 3 out of 4 interfaced with body, and leave the last of 4 as abstract. This is true that syntactically the base will implement the X and delegate it to children via abstract/virtual, but there is practically no difference in usage and behavior, for ABSTRACT base.

Comment: @Jules hmm I don't think it's necessary. It would be to store the memory address, which isn't really necessary. You can declare an object of a higher class and assign a derived class object to it. On the example above, `Child is Base` is true.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify an abstract method in Parent:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do something here...
    }

    public abstract void ForceChildToDoSomething();
}
```

This forces the child to implement it:

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    public override void ForceChildToDoSomething()
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

You will, however, now have an abstract Parent. So if you want to use the functionality in Parent, you'll need to do something like this:

```
Parent parent = new Child();
parent.DoSomething();
parent.ForceChildToDoSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, abstract:

```
public abstract Parent
{
  protected abstract bool CancelCanExecute(object param);
  //more stuff
}
```

It could also be `public`, but not `private`.

Now you can't have a derived class that doesn't either implement `CancelCanExecute` or is itself `abstract` so forcing further derived classes to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You should define an interface and then your code should accept only objects that implement that interface. While it is very tempting to use `abstract` and to create a common base class, this approach is (almost) wrong by definition (almost).

In C# and other languages that does not allow multiple-inheritance, creating a base class just to define an empty 'skeleton' that others must fill and forcing everyone to use it is **very limiting**. Everyone will have to inherit from it, thus, for example, they will not be able to reuse their own existing class hierarchies, or have to create tedious bridges or (...).

If your abstract-base-class have completely nothing else than a one/few/dozen/hundred abstract methods, events, and properties - it should have been an interface, because it only DEFINES the 'common requirements'.

The only reasonable reason to create an new abstract base with common thingies is to actually **provide** the default implementations. Still, with such base class, an interface should be defined too, the base should implement it and allow to override and maybe even mark something as actually abstract -- but still your code should refer to everything via interface, not the base class. Such abstract bases should be a help/shortcut for implementors, not mandatory. If someone wants to do everything from scratch - he will implement interface and ignore the base with example code, and your code will still beautifully work with that. Still, all the common code may be provided as a set of static helper classes operating on that very interfaces.

Abstract base classes are actually needed and cannot be supplanted with interfaces in some corner cases, for example when you have to force the derived classes to have a parameterful constructor, or where you yourself are bound to derive from somthing, ie. like WPF Visual or UIElement or DependencyObject --- the Microsoft's design is therefore flawed here a bit, too. They enforced deriving from base classes and it hits the developer in many places (like, ie. data model objects from EntityFramework not being DependencyObjects etc). Still, I think they should have abstracted from that - looking at Visual and friends, there are not that many internal routines that could not be lifted to interfaces.. I do not think they did it just 'because', rather, I think it was about performance and to cut casts/method dispatches.

Please note that everything I said does not exactly fit what you have presented in the question. There, you have already assumed that "the parent/base class will handle XYZ". This means, that you are resigning from the interface approach just at the very beginning. With interface, you will only define that click and cancelclick must exist, but you will not be able to enforce/provice the "base implementation". Such things you can do with base clases. Thus, I believe that you should take the open/mixed approach: define interface, define static reusable handlers, use only the interface, and provide a base class for some "lazy coders":

```
public interface IClickable
{
    ICommand CancelCommand { get; }
    void CancelClick();
    bool CanCancelClick();
}

public static class ClickableDefaultImpl
{
    public static void DefaultCancelClick(IClickable obj)
    {
        ... do the common things on the OBJ
    }
    public static bool DefaultCanCancelClick(IClickable obj)
    {
        ... do the common things on the OBJ
    }
}

public abstract class Clickable : IClickable
{
    public void CancelClick() { ClickableDefaultImpl.CancelClick(this); }
    public bool CanCancelClick() { return ClickableDefaultImpl.CanCancelClick(this);  }
}
```

This may seem very bloated, but it is quite open for customization. Though with the open-ness, there is almost no way to enforce that every one must use the "ClickableImpl". There are some ways, but .. they would include even more bloat and time/memory overhead, I think they are not worth describing now.

Remember to estimate who, how, and how much will use this code in future. If it is for one/two/five uses, stick with abstract bases. But if you sense dozens or hundreds of child implementations, you'd better add the little bloat - it may save much time later.

Comment: Think you mean for "public static class ClickableImpl" to implement IClickable...

Comment: no I do not. this is a STATIC class, uninstantiable. This is a common code base that every implementor of IClickable can use. For a sample (base) implementation of IClickable, there's a base class Clickable - it implements IClickable. It might be used to derive from it, but does not have to. If anyone wants to implement IClickable, it can either derive, or implement by it hand - but either way, he can use the common code that sits in the static class.

Comment: My mistake. Thanks for the clarification. That's what I get for reading and commenting too quickly! :)